# How to make a lightweight transparent http proxy that I can read http response in c++ for OSX

Tags: c++, macos, qt, http, proxy

What I want is not a proxy but to read all http responses (in text) that coming into my browser application.

I'm working with Qt so I need something can be loaded with Qt. So no much hope for mono.

Under windows I found Titanium Web Proxy / FiddlerCore / Nekoxy. Quite a lot of libraries written in C#. I wrote a wrapper to expose their functions to COM visible then I managed to load with Qt.

However I find nothing I can do with OSX.

I'm ok to write by myself but find little hint how to do it.

What I need is just three functions

1. startProxy(int port[, some handle to my app]): to redirect all http transitions pass through my proxy of 127.0.0.1:port
2. onAfterSessionComplete(string requestBodyAsString, string requestPathAndQuery, string responseBodyAsString, int resultCode, string mimeType, ): called when any http request is finished
3. shutdown()

So any hint to do this on OSX?
Best if there is some available libs open source like 
https://github.com/justcoding121/Titanium-Web-Proxy

BTW, I found mitmproxy, tinyproxy but I cannot find a good way to implement the 3 funcs above. And all I need is jut read http response that go through my app (written with Qt)

P.S. I know Qt has networkAccessManager but it no longer works with QtWebEngine.

Comment: Not entirely certain what you're trying to do, but note that Qt WebEngine has its own proxy support. You can read about it [here under the "proxy support"](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-overview.html) heading. This is because Chromium has its own native network stack that includes proxy support -- Qt detects the system proxy settings and passes them over to Chromium.

Comment: I need to read the responseBodyAsString. I can setup a proxy but I cannot read its contents. Thanks and I will add this to my question to make it clear.

Comment: It's 20 or 30 lines of code to write a TCP proxy - google *"c++ tcp proxy example"*.  Then from the captured data, discard the HTTP header parts.  Write some code and post it and specific problems if you're stuck.  Requesting external library/tutorial/tool recommendations is off topic on S.O..