# How to write a pass through tcp proxy in c++

Tags: c++, tcp, proxy, fiddlercore

I'm trying to write a proxy server that just pass what I read from remote to client. It should be something like FiddlerCore.

I follow this study but confused with the server ip and server port
http://www.partow.net/programming/tcpproxy/index.html

Just like FiddlerCore, I setup a internal proxy (inside my web-browser application) such as "127.0.0.1:13333". Then I setup proxy to this port. So that whenever my web-browser navigates to some url, I the internal proxy catch what it reads and return anything I read to my web-browser.

In this case, it seems that I only used one ip address and one port. But the example at the above link requires for two sets.
How can I setup the args or how can I change the code for fulfilling my usage?

FiddlerCore is not an option for me to use but what I need is exactly the same thing (except for its https part)

Comment: Is this a TCP proxy or an HTTP proxy?

Comment: actually I believe it should be an HTTP proxy. I asked another question here but they suggest me looking for tcp proxy though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36879446/how-to-make-a-lightweight-transparent-http-proxy-that-i-can-read-http-response-i

Comment: in addition, i'm targeting osx only.